# Unit speed spherical curve curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove that unit speed spherical curve $\beta$ satisfies following inequality
$$\kappa_{\beta}(s)\geqslant \frac1{R},$$
where $\kappa$ is curvature and $R$ is the radius of the sphere, that $\beta$ lies on.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{x}(s), \hat{t}(s), \hat{n}(s)$ be the position, tangent and normal vectors at arc length parametrization $s$.

Start from the equation of sphere $|\vec{x}(s)|^2 = R^2$, differentiate it once give us
$$\hat{t}(s)\cdot\vec{x}(s) = 0$$
Differentiate it again, we have
$$\hat{t}(s)\cdot\hat{t}(s) + \frac{d\hat{t}(s)}{ds}\cdot\vec{x}(s) = 0
\quad\implies\quad \kappa(s) \hat{n}(s)\cdot\vec{x}(s) = - 1$$

This leads to
$$R = |\vec{x}(s)| \ge |\hat{n}(s)\cdot\vec{x}(s)| = \frac{1}{\kappa(s)}
\iff \kappa(s) \ge \frac{1}{R}$$

Comment: Why does $|\vec{x}(s)|\geqslant |\hat{h}(s)\cdot \vec{x}(s)|$ hold?

Comment: @user334504 $\hat{n}(s)$ is a unit vector, so $\hat{n}(s)\cdot\vec{x}(s) = |\hat{n}(s)||\vec{x}(s)|\cos\theta = |\vec{x}(s)|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\hat{n}$ and $\vec{x}$.